# How to get a the retrieved value from query to a string. in Android

Tags: android, sql, database

I have a query to retrieve 3 fields by combining two tables. The values are in both tables
When date is given in edittest, I want all corresponding details on that date.
but i am not getting any out.

My method in DBAdapter class is given below

public Cursor gettranscation(String date)

```
{
    String sql="SELECT A.Acc_No,A.Cust_Name, T.Trans_Amnt FROM TransactionTable "
            + "T LEFT JOIN AccMaster A on A.Acc_ID = T.Acc_ID "
            + "WHERE T.Trans_Date ='"+ date +"' AND T.Trans_Type='debit' ORDER BY  T.Entry_Time asc";
    return db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{KEY_ACCNO,KEY_ACCCUSTNAME,KEY_TRANSAMOUNT});

}
```

My Activity class is given below

package com.example.accountmaster;

public class ReportActivity extends Activity{

```
private SQLiteDatabase sqldb;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.report_page);

    final EditText datetxt;
    Button showbttn ;

    datetxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_dateReport);
    showbttn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_show);
    final AccountDBAdapter db = new AccountDBAdapter(this);
    final String temp=datetxt.getText().toString();
    showbttn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try 
            {
                db.open();
                Cursor c = db.gettranscation(temp);

                if(c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        Display_error(c);
                    }while(c.moveToNext());
                }
                db.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("retrve error", ""+e.getMessage());
            }
            }
    });
}
private void Display_error(Cursor c) {

    Log.e("",
            "KEY_ACCID Id : " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "KEY_TRANSDATE :"
                    + c.getString(1) + "\n" + "KEY_TRANSTYPE : " + c.getString(2)); 

    Log.e("cursor error", ""+c.getColumnNames());
}
```

}

Comment: DBAdapter class is not an in-build android/SQLite class.Its a custom class so you need to provide us the code.
You can follow this link to understand SQLite
http://lecturesnippets.com/android-sqlite-dbadapter-class/

Answer (score 0):

You can get string like this

```
Cursor c = gettranscation(YOUR_DATE);
String str1 = c.getString(YOUR_COLUM_INDEX1); // Starting from 0
String str2 = c.getString(YOUR_COLUM_INDEX2);
```

*note: make sure your c.getCount(); must not return zero.*

Comment: Is the method in DBAdapter correct ??giving query and retrieving values to cursor ??